# QProcess started from a QMainWindow freezes window

Tags: qt5, qprocess, modality

I have a simple `QMainWindow` in which user can set some parameters.
I have three buttons which, when clicked, create a new `QProcess` displaying a `QMainWindow`. For example, main window's button `A` starts QProcess `A`, main window's button `B` starts process `B`, etc. 
I'd like to be able to interact with the main window, because now when I click the button the `QProcess` starts correctly, displaying another window etc, but the original main window stays *frozen* until the `QProcess` ends.

Is there a way to maintain the main window responsive, in order to be possible to interact with it **WHILE** the QProcess/QProcesses runs/run?

**EDIT:** here's how I start processes:

```
QProcess process;
process.execute("../../RRTStar/RRTStar", QStringList() << "--file" << "../../settings.conf");
```

where `RRTStar` is the name of the executable and `--file ../../settings.conf` are the command line parameters. Note that RRTStar is composed of a MainWindow and runs heavy computation using threads.

Comment: Show us how do you start processes?

Comment: Qt has very good docs. If your favorite editor/IDE doesn't support context sensitive help with Qt code, you should run Qt Creator on the side, so you can, for example, in this case, put cursor to method name `execute()`, hit F1, and then read the documentation, quoted in that answer below.

Comment: You didn't understand my question, it seems. I don't need a way to interact with the `QProcess`, that already works, since the new process window is responsive. The problem is that the main window stays frozen until the window process has finished and is up. There doesn't seem to be a way to solve this, all docs and questions are related to QDialog/QMessageBox modality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Information from the official documentation:

```
int QProcess::execute(const QString & program, const QStringList & arguments)
```

> Starts the program program with the arguments arguments in a new
>   process, **waits for it to finish**

If you want to make asynchronous non-blocking call, you need to use [QProcess::**start**()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#start):

```
void QProcess::start(const QString & program, const QStringList & arguments, OpenMode mode = ReadWrite)
```

About an **interaction with the process**: it inherites [QIODevice](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#details), so

> QProcess allows you to treat a process as a sequential I/O device. You
>   can **write** to and **read** from the process just as you would access a
>   network connection using QTcpSocket. You can then write to the
>   process's standard input by calling [write()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#write), and read the standard
>   output by calling [read()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#read), readLine(), and getChar(). Because it
>   inherits [QIODevice](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#details)...

```
process.write("Qt rocks!");
//...
QByteArray result = process.readAll();
```

Comment: I already tried this before asking the question. `QProcess::start()` correctly start the process and, since it takes a lot of time to finish, it immediately terminates it without waiting for it to be finished. I added a `waitForFinished()`, but of course that doesn't work, since 1) I don't know how much it will take to finish and 2) it again freezes the main window.
So, any suggestions?

Comment: I do not want to communicate with the process. I want it to freely run as long as it takes, and I also want the main window to be responsive.

Comment: Your process may terminate because of you create it (the process obj) in a local scope. Try to make the process object a class member or to use process = new QProcess();. You must be shure the the process's object has long life